# Ajax and Spring MVC: responseText doesn't work?

Tags: jquery, spring, spring-mvc

I have to get a String from a method in the Controller MVC, with Ajax. 
I wrote this code, but method `responseText` doesn't read the string that I return, when I use the method `removePrenot()` clicking a button.
How I can do it, without JQuery? Maybe I have to use GET, instead of POST? 
Thank you.

Controller Method

```
@RequestMapping(value="/delete", method=RequestMethod.POST)  
public void delete(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
  String str="Questo viene dal controller.";
  response.setContentType("text/plain");
  response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8"); 
  response.getWriter().write(str); 
 }
```

Javascript (Ajax)

```
function setXMLHttpRequest() {
    var xhr=null;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        xhr=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    return xhr;
}

var xhrObj=setXMLHttpRequest();

function removePrenot() {
    var url="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/delete";
    xhrObj.open("POST",url,true);
    xhrObj.onreadystatechange=updatePage;
    xhrObj.send(null);
}

function updatePage() {
    if(xhrObj.readyState===4) {
        alert("Return - "+xhrObj.responseText);
        var risp=xhrObj.responseText();
        document.getElementById("risposta").innerHTML=risp;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

I tried with jQuery, with these lines of codes but it still doesn't working.

```
function doAjaxPost() {
    $.ajax({type:"Post", url:"<%=request.getContextPath()%>/delete",    
    success:function(response) {  
      alert(response);   
    },  
    error:function(e) {  
      alert('Error: ' + e);   
    }  
   });
```

Comment: Did you check in the browser what the response looks like and could you post that output?

Comment: I found the solution with jQuery. HttpServletRequest e HttpServletResponse was missing. `@RequestMapping(value="/delete", method=RequestMethod.POST) public @ResponseBody String delete(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you are trying to do in Spring MVC can be accomplished using the following code

```
@RequestMapping(value="/delete", method= RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public String delete()  {
        return "Questo viene dal controller.";
    }
```

Also you'll probably be better off using jQuery for your client side ajax requests since it handles all the crossbrowser stuff internally

**UPDATE**:

As I said HttpRequest and HttpResponse are not needed in the Spring MVC Controller. It turns out that there where a few problems with the page. First of all there was a mismatch between jQuery versions (version 1.11.0 was present but version 1.10.1 was being requested). Second the jQuery script tag needs to be present before any other javascript that uses it.
Third the static resources where not being served correctly by Spring MVC. You need to move, css,js and images to a folder named `static` under the root web folder and then add the following configuration to dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/static/**" location="/static/" />

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter"/>
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping"/>
```

Accordingly all pages need to request resources using static/...

For example `static/js/jquery-1.11.0.js`

Comment: I tried with jQuery, you can see the code in the **EDIT** part.
It's right?

Comment: The javascript looks good (as long as the function is inside a jsp so <%=request.getContextPath()%> gets processed). Did you try the controller with the updated code?

Comment: Doesn't work. I have a doubt. 
In `url` I must put the address of method of Controller. Only `/delete` still not working. Maybe is here the problem, because I notice that the method isn't invoked.

Comment: I tried with var `url = window.location.host + "/ProjectSpringMVC/delete";` to get URL but Controller Method doesn't run.

Comment: No, doens't work. 
Can be that instead of POST, I have to use GET?

Comment: If I use GET or write the URL directly, will appear: State HTTP 405 - Request method "GET" not supported.

Comment: Tryi setting 'post' instead of 'Post' in your jQuery.

Comment: Nothing to do... the call doesn't invoke method.

Comment: The XMLHttpRequest.readyState return 0, so it isn't initialized. Maybe is here, how i can resolve?

Comment: I must have 20 reputation on Stack Overflow to talk there. :(

Comment: Ok, do you want to send me your whole project so I check and see what is wrong?

Comment: Sure, [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14850219/ProjectSpringMVC.rar) you can find the project.

Comment: I found the solution with jQuery. HttpServletRequest e HttpServletResponse was missing.
`@RequestMapping(value="/delete", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String delete(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception`

Now I have to update the new table without the row, dinamically. Any suggestion?